# ¿Cómo paso una linea de texto expecífica de un TextBox a otro?

Tags: c#

Tengo un botón que me busca y me resalta en un textBox que previamente he llenado cualquier palabra que yo le diga. Lo que quiero es que coja la linea en la que se encuentra esa palabra y me la pase/copie a otro textBox que tengo. Este es el botón:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        TextBox tb = (TextBox)this.Controls["ficherosBox1"];
        int posición = tb.Text.IndexOf(texto);                                                               
        string texto = textBox3.Text;
        tb.Focus();
        tb.SelectionStart = posición;
        tb.SelectionLength = texto.Length;

     }
```

Comment: La linea está delimitada por retornos de carro?

Comment: En el sitio desde donde los cojo (un .txt) si están delimitados pero al cargarlos al textBox se autoajusta y lo que debería ser una linea son 3.  Pero digamos que si

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando LINQ es muy sencillo. Lo que debes hacer es un [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) del texto usando los retornos de carro, y luego en el array resultante buscar la primera fila que contenga el texto buscado:

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)this.Controls["ficherosBox1"];
var lineaBuscada = tb.Text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                .Where(x => x.Contains(texto))
                                .FirstOrDefault();
if (lineaBuscada != null)
{
     tuOtroTextbox.Text = lineaBuscada;
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me funciona a la perfección.

Comment: No sabrías como hacer que mi botón de buscar pasase a la siguiente palabra que coincida con la búsqueda cada vez que le doy no?

Comment: @Guille no parece muy complejo. Piensa que `IndexOf` tiene una sobrecarga que admite el indice a partir del que empezar la búsqueda. Esto es una pista,si necesitas mas ayuda,  debes realizar una nueva pregunta :)